# solr binary files content indexed from datase

Tags: solr

Hello all,

I was wondering if somebody can help me figure this out.  I am new with solr and I am trying to index binary files such as .pdf, .docx... The problem is that my solr configuration indexes the files but when I run the query it does not display the content that resides within the files.

I am using the schema.xml as it comes by default.  
    
For the data-config.xml I am using this configuration:

```
<dataConfig>
 <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" 
                     user="Iam" batchSize="-1"/>
 <document>
     <entity name="data" datasource="mysql" recursive="true"
          query="select id, post, guid from posts'"
          >


        <field column="guid" name="content"/>
     </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

In the solrconfig.xml:

```
 <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

<requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
 </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

I hope someone can give me some tips. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DIH you can use Tika integration to index the rich content documents which can be held in either the file system or in DB as a blob field.

The Integration of Tika and DIH is already provided with Solr via [TikaEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TikaEntityProcessor)

Integration - [SOLR-1358](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1358)
Blob Handling - [SOLR-1737](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1737)

Comment: Hi Jayendra, thank you very much for your reply.  However, I am still stuck with pulling the content from the binary file stored in my database.  I followed the instructions in the link that you gave me but it does not work for me.  Is there anything else that I might be missing?